# Xcode 9 Beta 3 - Where is iOS11 Simulator?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9-beta

I have just installed XCode 9 beta 3.

But I don't see an iOS 11 version under Pref, Components.

How can I setup an iOS simulator?

Comment: did you find out how to install it?

Answer (score 6):

1) Open the Devices and Simulators window:

`Window` -> `Devices and Simulators`

2) Click the plus in the lower lefthand corner

You will see dialog to add a new simulator

3) Select a device (i.e. iPhone 7) that supports iOS 11 and click `create`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue only seeing iPhone 5 and 6 sims and not able to create / download iPhone 7 simulator with iOS11. My solution was to move Xcode 9 beta 3 from the downloads folder into the Applications folder along side xcode 8. I didn't realise it was still in the DL folder. Once launched from the Applications folder Xcode 9 beta 3 loaded with all the sims in place. Worth checking if your's is still in the downloads folder too with a previous version of Xcode in the Applications folder.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to add a (new) simulator

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Add Additional Simulator**". That will open **'Device & Simulator'** window.
3. Switch to **'Simulator'** tab.
4. There are three field in simulator tab.
5. Click on **'+'** icon, on left bottom corner of window.
6. Simulator Name: *Enter simulator name here*
7. Device Type: *Select **iPad** from this dropdown list*
8. OS Version: *Select OS version from this dropdown list*
9. Click on **'Create'**

A new simulator will be added in your Simulator option list.

Look at this snapshot to understand flow of above steps:
[image]

And if there is no simulator/OS version in simulator list, you're looking for,

1. Click on **Simulator** icon and open simulator list.
2. At the end of list, there is an option to add new simulator "**Download Simulator**". That will open **'Component'** window (from Xcode >> Preferences).
3. Select/click simulator from list, which you need to download.

Look at this snapshot:
[image]